# Why creating an object in Java using Singleton is so slow?

Tags: java, performance, constructor, singleton

Recently I made a class Singleton, where was a method returning the object `myInstance` of class Singleton. It was something like:

```
private final static Singleton myInstance = new Singleton();
```

After that I coded entire constructor, which was private, lets say:

```
private Singleton(){
   doStuff()
}
```

However the performance was terrible. Maybe someone can give me a hint why `doStuff()` is much slower then when I don't use Singleton? I guess it has something to do with calling the constructor while declaring variables, but can someone share some info about that?

I have no idea why is that, I tried to search for explanation, but I couldn't find it.

Edit: the dostuff function includes stuff like opening files/reading them/using regexp on them, using levenstein function[which by profiler was the slowest part of the code].
When running that levenstein from constructor while using singleton the speed of levenstein function took around 10 seconds. After the object was created the call on this function inside this singleton object took only 0.5 seconds. Now, when not using singleton, calling the levenstein function from the constructor is also 0.5 seconds, prior to 10 seconds when it was done by the singleton. The code for the function is as follows:
["odleglosci" is just a simple map]

```
 private static int getLevenshteinDistance(String s, String t) {

    int n = s.length(); // length of s
    int m = t.length(); // length of t

    int p[] = new int[n + 1]; //'previous' cost array, horizontally
    int d[] = new int[n + 1]; // cost array, horizontally
    int _d[]; //placeholder to assist in swapping p and d

    // indexes into strings s and t
    int i; // iterates through s
    int j; // iterates through t

    char t_j; // jth character of t

    int cost; // cost

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        p[i] = i * 2;
    }
    int add = 2;//how much to add per increase
    char[] c = new char[2];
    String st;
    for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
        t_j = t.charAt(j - 1);
        d[0] = j;

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            cost = s.charAt(i - 1) == t_j ? 0 : Math.min(i, j) > 1 ? (s.charAt(i - 1) == t.charAt(j - 2) ? (s.charAt(i - 2) == t.charAt(j - 1) ? 0 : 1) : 1) : 1;//poprawa w celu zmniejszenia wartosci czeskiego bledu
            if (cost == 1) {
                c[0] = s.charAt(i - 1);
                c[1] = t_j;
                st = new String(c);
                if (!odleglosci.containsKey(st)) {
                    //print((int) c[0]);
                    //print((int) c[1]);
                } else if (odleglosci.get(st) > 1) {
                    cost = 2;
                }

            } else {
                c[0] = s.charAt(i - 1);
                c[1] = t_j;
                st = new String(c);

                if (!odleglosci.containsKey(st)) {
                    // print((int) c[0]);
                    // print((int) c[1]);
                } else if (odleglosci.get(st) > 1) {
                    cost = -1;
                }
            }

            d[i] = Math.min(Math.min(d[i - 1] + 2, p[i] + 2), p[i - 1] + cost);
        }


        _d = p;
        p = d;
        d = _d;
    }
    return p[n];
}
```

I didn't thought that the code in here could have any relevance to the question I asked, that's why I did not include it before, sorry.

Comment: Without the actual initialization code, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Please post the code to `doStuff()`.

Comment: And just how slow is "terrible"? It really shouldn't be significantly slower.

Comment: Have you actually used a profiler to verify this?

Comment: I'm gonna call it the programming gods' retribution for calling forth singletons in vain.

Comment: To answear questions - yes I have used profiler, slower from 0,5 sec to 10 sec.
Initialization code is done in main: Singleton s=Singlet.getInstace(), where getInstances returns myInstance[as simple as possible].

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is slow is because `doStuff()` is slow.